# Android Programming Tutorials: #6

Tags: android

I started working through the tutorials in Mark L Murphy's book "Android Programming Tutorials". In Tutorial #6, they are starting to work with tabs. I copied the code:

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.restaurants);
    spec.setIndicator("List", getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.list));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.details);
    spec.setIndicator("Details", getResources()
    .getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant));
    getTabHost().addTab(spec);

    getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);
```

into my application, and got syntax errors on "getTabHost". 
I am using

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

How do I clear the "The method getTabHost() is undefined for the type ListerApp" error? Am I missing an import?

Answer (score 6):

Does your class extend [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) or Activity?  I think it will need to extend [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

Comment: Thank you!!!! 
forehead_slap! 
I have stared at that thing for hours, trying to figure out which widget i missed.